# Unexpected end of input, expected the token }

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know how to fix this error when trying to run `npx flow`?

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of codes or errors, put the text directly in the post, with the proper formating.

Comment: Please add error as a text as well as image. It will be helpful to search or better readability.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by adding declarations in `.flowconfig`

```
[declarations]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/resolve/.*
```